# Why nitrousio config secret key base gives error Rails app's config?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, webrick, secret-key

I am getting the below error in my rails application.

I run Ruby on Rails app, I click in preview and I got as below:

```
Internal Server Error You must set config.secret key base in your app's
config

DEPRECATION WARNING: You didn't set config.secret_key_base. Read the upgrade documentation to learn more about this new config option. (called from service at /home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0
-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138)                                                                                                                                                   
[2014-02-18 21:48:14] ERROR RuntimeError: You must set config.secret_key_base in your app's config.                                                                                               
        /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:145:in `env_config'                                                                                   
        /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:507:in `call'                                                                                              
        /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'                                                                                          
        /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'                                                                                                      
        /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'                                                                                            
        /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'                                                                                        
        /home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'                                                                                            
        /home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'                                                                                                 
        /home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Can somebody please help me for this.

Thanks

Comment: is your secret_key_base set?  You'll find it in `config/initializers/secret_token.rb` and it will be defined in a line of code such as `AppName::Application.config.secret_key_base = "asdfJSSKDJFH78&KJHFDSDSFSDklkjfdLKJ"`

Answer (score 2):

You should, I think, have a file in your `config/initializers` directory called `secret_token.rb`.  Inside that file you'll see something like:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Your secret key is used for verifying the integrity of signed cookies.
# If you change this key, all old signed cookies will become invalid!

# Make sure the secret is at least 30 characters and all random,
# no regular words or you'll be exposed to dictionary attacks.
# You can use `rake secret` to generate a secure secret key.

# Make sure your secret_key_base is kept private
# if you're sharing your code publicly.
MyApp::Application.config.secret_key_base = 'de6156670dfadf0101011000112310980198236544e55623a143c9ae5254842b2c66fcc59849'
```

If it's not there, try creating one.

Comment: i check that i find the file ? what i can also to fix this Error

Comment: Catarse::Application.config.secret_token = find_secure_token
Catarse::Application.config.secret_key_base = find_secure_key_base